# Handler cannot refresh the view when launching the Activity for the second time

Tags: android, refresh, handler

First, I launch `ActivityB`and click the `getUdpMsg` button. The `Handler` will receive the message and refresh the UI.

Then, I go back to `ActivityA`， launch `ActivityB` again, and click the same button. However, the UI is not refreshed.

But the UI setText successfully from log.

Why?

```
public Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            if (msg.what == 1) {
                receiveMsg = udpSocketReceive.receiveMsg;
                Log.d("test", "receive = " + receiveMsg);

                // 解析接收到的消息
                messageReceive = new MessageReceiveUDP(receiveMsg);

                messageReceive.parseUDPRecvMsg();

                if (!messageReceive.isValid()) {
                    Log.e("Error", "The received msg is invalid");
                } else {
                    Log.d("testt", "valid msg");
                    // 解析的结果显示在UI上
                    udpreceiveflag = true;
                    // udpSocketReceive.setLife(false);
                    setResultOnUI(messageReceive);
                    (new View(context)).invalidate();
                    Log.d("debug","after invalidate ip = " +chabanipTextView.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Why does not it work when I launch ActivityB again？

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on your question so I have to reply by an answer.

Two questions:

1. Are you sure if the message is really sent in the second time?
2. If it is, which I suppose it is sent in a different thread, is the thread started in the second time?

I had the same problem once. It came out to be after I finished my work on the thread I created (say it's called MyThread), MyThread is terminated. So the next time I "called" it by `MyThread.run()`, the works were running in the MainThread.

The solution is simple, **make sure MyThread is created again.**

### Edit

To make sure MyThread is created, use `Thread.start()` instead of `Thread.run()`.

Hope this helps (: